# Encryption and Decryption in java

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography

i want encrypt the text file from one class and should able to decrypt it from another class.
Here i have  successfully  encrypted a text file and stored into a string named "encryptedFile" in the class "endecryption.java".
But i want decrypt the same "encryptedFile" into another text file named "decryptedFile" from another class decryption.java,but instead of decryption it is encrypting again the encrypted files.

this is my endecryption.java class

```
class Endecryption {
   private static Cipher encrypt;

private static Cipher decrypt;



private static final byte[] initialization_vector = { 22, 33, 11, 44, 55, 99, 66, 77 };


 public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here
    String normalFile = "D:/ashok/ashk.txt";
    String encryptedFile="D:/ashok/aso.txt";


    try {



        SecretKey secret_key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES")

                .generateKey();

        AlgorithmParameterSpec alogrithm_specs = new IvParameterSpec(

                initialization_vector);
  // set encryption mode ...

        encrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        encrypt.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secret_key, alogrithm_specs);



        // set decryption mode

       // encrypt file

        encrypt(new FileInputStream(normalFile), new FileOutputStream(

                encryptedFile));

     System.out.println("End of Encryption/Decryption procedure!");


    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException

            | InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException

            | IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}

 private static void encrypt(InputStream input, OutputStream output)

        throws IOException {



    output = new CipherOutputStream(output, encrypt);

    writeBytes(input, output);

}


private static void writeBytes(InputStream input, OutputStream output)

        throws IOException {

    byte[] writeBuffer = new byte[512];

   int readBytes = 0;



    while ((readBytes = input.read(writeBuffer)) >= 0) {

        output.write(writeBuffer, 0, readBytes);

    }



    output.close();

    input.close();

}
```

this is my decrypt.java class

```
 public class decryption {
   private static Cipher encrypt;

private static Cipher decrypt;


private static final byte[] initialization_vector = { 22, 33, 11, 44, 55, 99, 66, 77 };




/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO code application logic here


    String encryptedFile = "D:/ashok/aso.txt";

    String decryptedFile = "D:/ashok/amii.txt";

    try {



        SecretKey secret_key = KeyGenerator.getInstance("DES")

                .generateKey();

        AlgorithmParameterSpec alogrithm_specs = new IvParameterSpec(

                initialization_vector);
          // set encryption mode ...

        // set decryption mode

        decrypt = Cipher.getInstance("DES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");

        decrypt.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secret_key, alogrithm_specs);

        // encrypt file

    // decrypt file

      decrypt(new FileInputStream(encryptedFile), new FileOutputStream(

                decryptedFile));

        System.out.println("End of Encryption/Decryption procedure!");


    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException

            | InvalidKeyException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException

            | IOException e) {

        e.printStackTrace();

    }

}



private static void decrypt(InputStream input, OutputStream output)

        throws IOException {



    input = new CipherInputStream(input, decrypt);

    writeBytes(input, output);

}



private static void writeBytes(InputStream input, OutputStream output)

        throws IOException {

    byte[] writeBuffer = new byte[512];

   int readBytes = 0;



    while ((readBytes = input.read(writeBuffer)) >= 0) {

        output.write(writeBuffer, 0, readBytes);

     }



     output.close();

     input.close();

   }

 }
```

Comment: Just a note: It is best practice to capitalize classes in Java, i.e. `public class Decryption`.

Comment: You forget to close both your input and output files. Also, use java.nio.file and try-with-resources.

Comment: An encrypted file is not text. Don't call it `.txt`.

Comment: Note that `CipherInputStream` tends to swipe `BadPaddingException`'s under the rug. You'll never see a bad decrypt (e.g. because of an incorrect key).